# How to sum values from two unrelated tables group by state

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum the number of people age 17 or younger from two different tables unrelated to each other. The first table has set of states and the second table has another different set of state. I want to have a list of all the states with the number of people age 17 or younger. Here is my code but I keep getting an error

```
SELECT 
   (
    SELECT SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.CaseKeyIndicator2017
    Where FiscalYear = 2017
    GROUP BY StateName
    ) +
    (
    SELECT SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.KeyIndicator2017
    Where FiscalYear = 2017
    GROUP BY StateName
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help . . . as would an explanation of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the tables may not have the exact states, you can use a `full join` or two aggregations.

So:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.StateName, k.StateName) as StateName,
       c.[Age 17 or Younger], k.[Age 17 or Younger]
       (COALESCE(c.[Age 17 or Younger], 0) + COALESCE(k.[Age 17 or Younger], 0)) as [Age 17 or Younger]
FROM (SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
      FROM NamrsFrozen2017.CaseKeyIndicator2017
      WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
      GROUP BY StateName
     ) c FULL JOIN
     (SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
      FROM NamrsFrozen2017.KeyIndicator2017
      WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
      GROUP BY StateName
     ) k
     ON c.StateName = k.StateName;
```

Note that your query does not work because the subqueries are returning multiple rows (one for each state).  However, they are being used in the context of a *scalar* subquery, which can return at most one row.

Comment: Yep, but I would use `+` on the second line instead of `,`. Upvoting anyway.

Comment: If I want to add another table that has all the state names. How would I do that. Any help is appreciated  @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @G.Aurelien . . . That table would be first in the `FROM` clause and then you would use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `FULL JOIN`s.  Some of the `COALESCE()`s would go away too.

Comment: FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState 
     Left Join 
      (SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger] 
      FROM NamrsFrozen2017.CaseKeyIndicator2017
      WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
      GROUP BY StateName
     ) c FULL Outer JOIN
     (SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
      FROM NamrsFrozen2017.KeyIndicator2017
      WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
      GROUP BY StateName
     ) k

Comment: Like this @GordonLinoff  I keep getting an error Keep in mind the third table has just the state names

Comment: @G.Aurelien . . . You need `ON` clauses.  You might want to ask another question.